# How do I delete a Kafka topic from the cli?

Tags: apache-kafka

```
$ kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list | grep my-topic
my-topic
$ kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic my-topic
Topic my-topic is marked for deletion.
Note: This will have no impact if delete.topic.enable is not set to true.
$ kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list | grep my-topic
my-topic - marked for deletion
```

It's been hours since then, and the topic has still not been deleted.

I've seen suggestions that I should put `delete.topic.enable` in my `server.properties` and restart kafka. I've tried this. It hasn't worked.

```
$ grep -F delete.topic.enable /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
delete.topic.enable = true
```

(Why wouldn't this be set by default?)

In any case, these suggestions have all been for kafka 0.* and I am on a newer version.

```
$ brew list --versions kafka
kafka 1.1.0
```

How do I delete topics?

I can shutdown kafka and zookeeper, run `rm -r /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs /usr/local/var/run/zookeeper/data`, then start zookeeper and kafka again. But this is rather drastic. Surely there should be some way of persuading `kafka-topics` to actually delete a topic?

Comment: Sorry, I misread you message and marked my response for deletion to avoid confusion. If you have `delete.topic.enable` set to `true` the topic should automatically get removed in an async fashion. This issue has happened to me a few times before, and it turned out that some producer/consumer process is still running on that topic. After finding the process and killing it, the topic is removed. Have you checked for such processes?

Comment: By the way, [as of Kafka 1.0, deletion enabled is the default](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5384)

Comment: @vahid I had not checked for these processes. There are none now, but I have regained the ability to delete topics by other means. I will check in the future if the problem reoccurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the suggestion of a colleague, I

- shut down Kafka and Zookeeper
- added the line `listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092` to `/usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties`
- restarted Zookeeper and Kafka

Now I can delete topics again. I don't know why this should work, but suspect it is related to a recent macOS upgrade.

Comment: I don't like this answer because it doesn't provide a reason why it should work. But I'm accepting it because it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The command you're using is the recommended way to delete a topic.

Unfortunately there are a few reasons why a topic can stay stuck in "marked for deletion" state.

If you check the controller logs, you might see why it's not able to delete it. In the controller logs, all lines from the Deletion Manager are prefixed with `Topic Deletion Manager`.

Periodically, you should see messages like `Handling deletion for topics ...`. In case the controller has given up the deletion, it should have logged it, with this format: `Halted deletion of topics ...`.

If you want to force the deletion, you can try:

- Deleting the topic details in Zookeeper. Using `zookeeper-shell.sh`, run `rmr /brokers/topics/TOPIC_NAME`
- Bouncing the controller

Finally if none of this works, you can, as hinted, delete the log data on disk/

Comment: I checked `/usr/local/var/log/kafka/kafka_output.log` and it doesn't contain the messages you describe, unfortunately. The only messages matching `/deletion/i` are along the lines of `Log for partition <foo> is renamed to <foo>.<hash>-delete and is scheduled for deletion (kafka.log.LogManager)`

Comment: I mean the controller logs. At any time, one broker in your cluster should be the controller. By default, it logs its actions in a file called `controller.log`: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties#L48-L52

Comment: Ah, right. Found the file at `/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/1.1.0/libexec/logs/controller.log`. It seems to rotate every hour. No clues in any of them, though.